# Typescript Type Guard in callback function return incorect type guard (return guard type with additional undefined type)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wrote a `filterObject` function that accept an object and a callback function as input the function. For the callback function, I described the Type and a type guard. But for some reason, the type guard does not work out correctly.

Below is the function code

```
type Entry<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T];

const filterObject = <T extends { [key: PropertyKey]: T[keyof T] }, S extends T>(
    obj: T,
    callback: (val: Entry<T>) => val is Entry<S>,
) => {
    return Object.entries(obj).filter(callback);
};
```

Here I call the `filterObject` function with a type guard

```
type A = {
    a?: number;
    b: number;
};

const obj: A = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
};

const data = filterObject(obj, (val): val is Entry<Required<A>> => {
    return true;
});
```

After execution the `filterObject` function.
The variable `data` type is `[string, number | undefined][]` but should be in theory `[string, number][]`.
As the callback type guard is `(val is  Entry<Required<A>>)` setted with `Required<A>` which remove the optional flag(?) from object fields

**Expected behavior:** the variable `data` type is `[string, number][]` 
**Actual behavior:** the variable `data` type is `[string, number | undefined][]`

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiAPAFQHxQLxQN4BQAkANoDSUAlnFANYQgD2AZlGgLoBcU5ANG+XbsA3AQC+Jek1YdRBAMaM4AZ2BRmlADbAIiAPIAjAFYR5a3OigQAHjrgATZfh5TuABUSNIiUGQZcBKRY2digxfgBlK1sIBydMAApiRmNuNF5ieQBDTU0DLPlabgSANxzueCRUTABKHCwyzSonSuQUCIwMuuwsQiJECGAAV0QaQxMzADpYpEoIZQSUoxrJjW1dBOzc-MKa0TE5UEgoAEEcfGIsgH5uOCGAWwNdUSIDW4enxH25AHofqAAYoxEFAhg5dKosg4oAlgAALaADYajKBHaAAcyGWUQ9igwS2eQKtHUYLMlCUdWoUDhjBKulRCKgACFUeAIAQ0czzq1UAAlCAARyGlAG9hQJwwGDkihUaiW3DOuD6WW4AEYMq9uAAmDIHAgEP5QexZYBZVnHShOEiqRDUdH8O6PekAH1B4I0cAg9nYJFCBiGamUNKGmlxTyoNHhEGBIB4NrtDo+uh97AUSlURpNZtwax0+mMpmAi2M-FKORq3EazVgCDa-KFIq94sl9Qu-UGI0jiCGEH2e31MozAycuGNppIAAYfaqRFBDQiBuboJaYY7PlBXWD7BAPV66v7A8HQ1Bw1SozHV0nEDUDf8Tk4o1ACTtiZyAOJYnHVstNFc1qooPWwqis2GB1Mogw6LiADulDwlAQGNmKEq3lA0FwpQ8hwlAAz3LS0BeMA5JwDk6iaFk6IJFcdTMJ49x4gWZjqHMobKPqqEwNYkBmF6J4QHCWQlOSiDcI+ZS2lkBiaNAY5mpyK7WrMcD2lAa7Jr6qEnGYWJNE8AlCcComMuJlCSdJmamku1aKbaymJk6IKbu61BeimQA)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't know that `Object.entries(obj)` returns `Array<Entry<typeof obj>>`; if you want it to treat it that way you need to assert that this happens, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOr76W).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz (Does that fully address the question?) Yes, thank you for help!
(If so I'll write up an answer explaining) Ok, after this I can accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: @jcalz How I understand here is Object.entries(obj) without cast as **Array<Entry<T>>**, typescript don't apply **type Guard** as the return type of function  **Object.entries(obj)** is **[string, T[keyof T]][]** which conflicts with the type of **Type Gard of the callback function** **Array<Entry<T>>**.
I right understand?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.  I will write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see why `filterObject()` does not return `Array<Entry<S>>`.

The [TypeScript library definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7216ee0bb821b4b565d54c52dcbf788a3fdf7062/src/lib/es2017.object.d.ts#L18) for [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) looks like

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T; } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
}
```

meaning that when you call `Object.entries(obj)` on `obj` of a type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `{[s: string]: T[keyof T]}`, then it returns a value of type `Array<[string, T[keyof T]]>`.

On that result you call [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a callback of type `(val: Entry<T>) => val is Entry<S>`. The [TypeScript library definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7216ee0bb821b4b565d54c52dcbf788a3fdf7062/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1450-L1456) for `filter()` looks like

```
interface Array<U> {
  filter<V extends U>(cb: (v: U, i: number, a: U[]) => value is V, thisArg?: any): V[];
  filter(cb: (v: U, i: number, a: U[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): U[];
}
```

If you want `filterObject()` to return `Array<Entry<S>>`, then you'd need to call the first call signature of `filter()`.  And therefore you'd need to instantiate its type parameter `V` with the type argument `Entry<S>`.  But that would require `Entry<S>` to extend `U` which has been instantiated with `[string, T[keyof T]]`.  And it does not.  The first element of `Entry<S>` is only constrained to `string | number | symbol` and therefore is not seen as assignable to `string`.

So the first call signature is skipped and everything falls apart quickly from here.  The second call signature doesn't do any narrowing, so the output type for the whole function `filterObject()` is just `[string, T[keyof T]][]`...  and then all hope is lost.  Your subsequent call where `obj` is of type `A` will always yield `Array<[string, number | undefined]>` because `A[keyof A]` is `number | undefined`.  Oops.

---

There are various ways to fix this.

I think the most straightforward is for you to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `Object.entries(obj)` returns `Array<Entry<T>>`, because `Entry<S>` *is* assignable to `Entry T` and the first call signature succeeds:

```
const filterObject = <T extends { [key: PropertyKey]: T[keyof T] }, S extends T>(
    obj: T,
    callback: (val: Entry<T>) => val is Entry<S>,
) => {
    const entries: Array<Entry<T>> = Object.entries(obj);
    return entries.filter(callback);
};
```

and now `filterObject()` returns `Array<Entry<S>>` and you get the narrowing behavior you're looking for:

```
type A = { a?: number; b: number; };
const obj: A = { a: 1, b: 2, };
const data = filterObject(obj, (val): val is Entry<Required<A>> => true)
const res = data[0][1]; // number
```

It's possible that you could try to play around with your definition of `Entry` or your constraints for the `T` type parameter and get the call to succeed, but the above assertion is simple enough and gets the job done.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiAPAFQHxQLxQN4BQAkANoDSUAlnFANYQgD2AZlGgLoBcU5ANG+XbsA3AQC+Jek1YdRBAMaM4AZ2BRmlADbAIiAPIAjAFYR5a3OigQAHjrgATZfh5TuABUSNIiUGQZcBKRY2digxfgBlK1sIBydMAApiRmNuNF5ieQBDTU0DLPlabgSANxzueCRUTABKHCwyzSonSuQUCIwMuuwsQiJECGAAV0QaBMMTMwA6WKRKCGUElKM6rKcAQURELNRW6owMGqmNbV0E7Nz8wprRMTkCAlBIKHWcfGIsgH5uOCGAWwMulERAMP3+gMQtzkT2gACE3nsUAAlCAARyGlAG9hQ6wOckUKjUy24r1wfSy3AAjBkQdwAEwZO4PAmqKD2LLALJvE46fTGUzAJbGfilHI1biNZqwBBtFHozEQbG4rA9d79QYjGhIIYQW43B4KJSsgZOXDszkkAAM7BIlJEUAA9A6oL8AboCEA)